# Extract letters from a string at different positions in R

Tags: r, substr

I have two columns and I would like to extract letters from different positions. The goal is to show what letter was used in Col2 to replace the letter in Col1. The letters will be extracted from Col1 and Col2 based on Position column. In the Position column the letter "E" indicates the location that will be used to extract the letters.

[image]

Here is what I tried using `substr` function:

```
df <- data.frame ("Col1" = c("Stores","University","Street","Street Store"), 
       "Col2" = c("Ostues", "Unasersity", "Straeq","Straeq Stuwq"), 
       "Position" = c("EMMEMM","MMEEMMMMMM", "MMMEME","MMMEMEMMMEEE"), 
       "Desired Output" = c("S|O , r|u","i|a , v|s","e|a , t|q", "e|a , t|q , o|u , r|w , e|q"))


n <- which(strsplit(df$Position,"")[[1]]=="E")
#output for the first row:
# [1] 1  4

#then I used substr function:
substr(df$Col1, n, n)

#only the first character returned as below:
[1] "S"

#desired output for first row:
S|O , r|u
```

Comment: Yes, first three columns are input. I added the sample data in reproducible format as suggested.

Comment: Your `position` column doesn't seem to line up with `Col1` and `Col2` in line 1 of your example. Rows 2 and 3 show an E for each letter that was actually changed, as opposed to just the letters that are colored differently. In the first line, the first four letters have been changed going from `Col1` to `Col2`. Is `Position` meant to be taken as a given? Or is it calculated in your data?

Comment: @brittenb the Position column is given. I made a typo when entering the data.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, @mrflick has the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i'll just make a helper function to extract a character from a position

```
subchr <- function(x, pos) {
  substring(x, pos, pos)
}
```

Then you can find all the positions you want to extract

```
extract_at <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Position), ""), 
    function(x) which(x=="E"))
```

And put those together to get the output you want

```
mapply(function(e, a, b){
  paste(subchr(a, e), subchr(b,e), sep="|", collapse=" , ")
}, extract_at, as.character(df$Col1), as.character(df$Col2))
# [1] "S|O , r|u" "i|a , v|s" "e|a , t|q"
```

Comment: when I run the last part of the code to get the output, I get the error: Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Is your real data.frame named `df`? (That's also a built in function in R). I would guess that maybe there's one instance of `df` you didn't change to your real variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like :

```
df %>% mutate(x=str_replace_all(chartr("M",".",Position),"E","\\(\\.\\)"),
          output=paste0(str_replace(Col1,x,"\\1"),"|",str_replace(Col2,x,"\\1"),
                  " , ",str_replace(Col1,x,"\\2"),"|",str_replace(Col2,x,"\\2")))
#        Col1       Col2   Position Desired.Output              x    output
#1     Stores     Ostues     EMMEMM      S|O , r|u     (.)..(.).. S|O , r|u
#2 University Unasersity MMEEMMMMMM      i|a , v|s ..(.)(.)...... i|a , v|s
#3     Street     Straeq     MMMEME      e|a , t|q     ...(.).(.) e|a , t|q
```

Data:

```
    df <- data.frame ("Col1" = c("Stores","University","Street"), 
       "Col2" = c("Ostues", "Unasersity", "Straeq"), 
       "Position" = c("EMMEMM","MMEEMMMMMM", "MMMEME"), 
       "Desired Output" = c("S|O , r|u","i|a , v|s","e|a , t|q"))
```